# Count columns of a result from with block?

Tags: sql-server

I am exploring provided code. I have various CTEs, and I want to count the columns in each CTE? Or select the differences in columns per CTE?

The below code will grab the count from a table in the DB, but I'm not sure how to apply this to CTEs?

```
select count(*) 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
where TABLE_CATALOG = 'db_name'
and TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I have various CTEs?"

Comment: What do you mean by `CTE` ? is it `Common Table Expression`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 `CTE` only exists within a query it is not a physical table

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: Do you mean views?

Comment: Yes I mean CTE = common table expression....so I have a couple queries in the form of CTEs, and I want to basically compare the column counts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Create CTE and then insert just one record into temp table , then query the sys.columns table to get the list of the columns in CTE

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp; 
go
With CTE1 as (select * from table_name)
select top 1 * into #temp from CTE1

SELECT count(*) FROM tempdb.sys.columns where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#temp')
```